# returning 404 in nginx location block

Tags: nginx, return, http-status-code-404

```
server{

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    listen 18081;
    root /home/maxou;
    error_page 404 /webserv/error/404.html;

    location \.css
    {
        root /home/maxou/webserv/error;
    }

    location ~ /images {
    return 404;
}
```

When I try to access a uri starting with images/ I get my custom 404.html error page but without the css.
The GET uri for my css is /images/somefile.css
and of course dont find it because it is located in /webserv/error.
I dont understand why the css extension block doesnt have the priority on the /images block since I have no optional modifier.
What am I doing wrong ?
How to return a 404 code with my custom html and css with the routes /images ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your location is wrong

```
location \.css
```

For regexp location, you must use **~** or **~*** modifier, like:

```
location ~* \.css
```

> [nginx location](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the “~” modifier (for case-sensitive >matching).

suppose *404.html* and *style.css* locate in **/var/www/html/custom_errors**,
**link** tag in *404.html*:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom_errors/style.css">`
then config will be something like:

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html{
  root /var/www/html/custom_errors;
  internal;
}
location ~ /images {
  return 404;
}
```

Now if request `http://hostname.tld/images`, you'll get custom 404 error page with your css style.